# main.cpp:18:20: error: cast from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers

I have literally re-wrote the code from my tutorial where it does work. Can someone please tell me why "(int)tablica" doesnt work while "tablica" does?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ile;

int main()
{
cout<<"ile liczb w tablicy: "<<endl;
cin>>ile;



int *tablica;
tablica = new int [ile];

   for(int i=0; i<ile; i++)
{
    cout<<(int)tablica<<endl;
    tablica++;
}


delete [] tablica;  
return 0;
}
```

im at work and dont have proper IDE so i use https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: Should not there be a `cout<<tablica[i]<<endl;` and remove `tablica++;` Why do you move the allocated pointer. You can not delete the pointer when you change it's address.

Comment: You need a better tutorial. This program has undefined behaviour because you `delete[]` a pointer you didn't get from `new[]`.

Comment: You saved the value returned by `new[]` to `tablica`. So far so good. You can `delete[]` it at this point. Next thing you do is `tablica++`. Now `tablica` stores something other than the value returned by `new[]`. You cannot `delete` it any more.

Comment: https://ideone.com/CGgnHs

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends of what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to print all numbers from your array, you should not try to use C-style cast your **pointer** to an **object of type int**. You just need to dereference the pointer this way `cout<<*tablica<<endl;`.

If you want to print addresses of your array's elements you do not need do anything at all, and just print them `cout<<tablica<<endl;`

In both cases, as n.m noticed in the comment, you should store another pointer to delete your array, because you modify your existing one, and in the end of the loop `tablica` doesn't pointing to the beginning of array.

```
int *tablica;
tablica = new int [ile];

int *originalPointer = tablica;

... increment and decrement tablica poitner so many times as you want ...

delete[] originalPointer;
```